# List currently defined functions in dash?

Tags: shell, dash-shell

I'd like to list the currently defined functions in `dash`. Is there any way of doing that?

The closest I've been able to come up with is `type` which can be used to test if a function exist, but other than that I'm stumped.

P.S. I'm talking about `dash` here (not `bash` or `zsh`).

Comment: Why do you want such a list? AFAIK dash script can not inherit functions from caller's environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at exec.c it seems that no, there is none - the table is static, there's no such functionality in the file and none of the exported functions (unsetfunc etc) appear to offer the possibility of iterating, so unless I missed something I'd say you'll need to write a patch :)