# How can you use pure unset shell builtin? Can you write shell scripts that are immune to tampering?

Tags: bash, security, sh, zsh, dash-shell

I mean I want to use `unset` that is not a shell function itself. If I could do that, I could make sure that `command` is pure by running

```
#!/bin/sh
{ \unset -f unalias command [; \unalias unset command [ } 2>/dev/null;
# make zsh find *builtins* with `command` too:
[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && options[POSIX_BUILTINS]=on
```

If I am using Debian Almquist shell (dash), I think I can rely that `\unset` is pure. At least I could not define a shell function named `unset` in `dash`. Whereas in `bash` or in `zsh` I could define `unset() { echo fake unset; }`, and thereafter I am unable to unset the function: `\unset -f unset` outputs "fake unset".

Relating to this, in a `bash` script, one can export a function by `export -f <function name>` so that it can be used in `bash` scripts called by the script. However, the same does not work in `dash` scripts. I wonder, if I have to worry about a command being defined as a shell function outside a script file I am writing, if I am using `dash`? How about other POSIX compatible shells?

Comment: As partial answer, `POSIXLY_CORRECT=` ensures that shell function is not used, when`unset` is called in Bash. Same applies for any POSIX special built-in utility. This does not work for Zsh shell, though.

Comment: List of [POSIX special built-in utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14)

Comment: Actually, as for Bash, `POSIXLY_CORRECT=` is not needed, if the script is invoked as 'sh'. E.g. if there is a hashbang `#!/bin/sh`, and the script is run by its name. See [document](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/POSIX) which is linked from bash manual page.

Answer (score 16):

Note: The following applies to all major POSIX-compatible shells, except where noted otherwise: `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`. (`dash`, the Debian Almquist Shell, is the default shell (`sh`) on Debian-based Linux distros such as Ubuntu).

- **`unset` having its original meaning** - [a builtin that can undefine shell *functions* with its `-f` option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#unset) - is the **key to ensuring that any other shell keyword, command, or builtin has its original meaning**.

  - Starting with an unmodified `unset`, you can ensure an unmodified `shopt` and/or `command`, and together they can be used to bypass or undefine any aliases or shell functions that may shadow shell keywords, builtins, and external utilities.
  - As an alternative to *undefining* functions, `command` can be used to *bypass* them, including those that may have been defined *outside* of your code, through the environment;
    *exporting* functions, as only `bash` supports, is only *one* of these mechanisms; different shells have different ones and may support several - see below.
- **Only `dash`, `ksh`, and `bash` *when in POSIX compatibility mode* guarantee that `unset` wasn't redefined:**

  - `dash` and `ksh` are safe, because they *don't allow defining* a *function* named `unset`, as you've discovered, and any alias form can be bypassed by invoking as `\unset`.
  - `bash`, *when in POSIX compatibility mode*, allows you to *define* a function named `unset`, but *ignores* it when you invoke `unset`, and always executes the builtin, as you've later discovered.

    - Given that **POSIX compatibility mode restricts Bash's feature set and modifies its behavior**, it is usually not desirable to run your Bash code in it. At the **bottom of this post** is an implementation of the **workaround** you suggest, which *temporarily* actives POSIX compatibility mode in order to ensure that no `unset` *function* is defined.
- Sadly, as far as I know, in **`zsh`** - and also in `bash`'s default mode -  there is **no way to guarantee that `unset` itself hasn't been redefined**, and there may be other POSIX-like shells that behave similarly.

  - Calling it as `\unset` (quoting any part of the name) would bypass an *alias* redefinition, but not a *function* redefinition - and to undo that you would need the original `unset` itself: catch 22.
- Thus, **with no control over the execution environment, you cannot write shell scripts that are fully immune to tampering**, ***unless* you know that your code will be executed by `dash`, `ksh`, or `bash` (with the workaround in place)**.

  - If you're willing to assume that `unset` has not been tampered with, **the most robust approach** is to:

    - Use `\unset -f` to ensure that `unalias` and `command` are unmodified (not shadowed by a shell function: `\unset -f unalias command`)

      - Functions, unlike aliases, must be undefined *explicitly*, by name, but not all shells provide a mechanism to enumerate all defined functions, unfortunately (`typeset -f` works in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, but [`dash` appears to have no mechanism at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24893122/45375)), so that undefining *all* functions is not always possible.
    - Use `\unalias -a` to remove all aliases.
    - Then invoke *everything* with `command [-p]`, except for functions *you* have defined.  When invoking *external utilities*, use *explicit paths* when possible, and/or, in the case of *standard utilities*, use `command -p`, which uses a minimal `$PATH` definition restricted to standard locations (run `command -p getconf PATH` to see that definition).

---

**Additional info:**

- Per POSIX, quoting any part of a command name (e.g., `\unset`) bypasses any *alias* form or *keyword* form (*reserved word* in POSIX and `zsh` parlance) by that name - but *not* shell *functions*.
- Per POSIX, `unalias -a` undefines all *aliases*. There is no equivalent, POSIX-compliant command for undefining all *functions*.

  - *Caveat*: older `zsh` versions do *not* support `-a`; as of at least `v5.0.8`, however, they do.
- Builtin `command` can be used to bypass keywords, aliases, functions in `bash`, `dash`, and `ksh` - in other words: `command` only executes *builtins* and *external utilities*. By contrast, `zsh` by default *also* bypasses *builtins*; to make `zsh` execute builtins too, use `options[POSIX_BUILTINS]=on`.
- The following can be used to execute *external* utilities named `<name>` only, across all shells:
  `"$(command which <name>)" ...`
  Note that while `which` is not a POSIX utility, it is widely available on modern Unix-like platforms.
- Precedence of command forms:

  - `bash`, `zsh`: alias > shell keyword > shell function > builtin > external utility
  - `ksh`, `dash`: shell keyword > alias > shell function > builtin > external utility
  - I.e.: In `bash` and `zsh` an alias can override a shell keyword, while in `ksh` and `dash` it cannot.
- `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` - but not `dash` - all allow a nonstandard function signature, `function <name> { ...`, as an alternative to the POSIX-compliant `<name>() { ...` form.

  - The `function` syntax is the prerequisite for:

    - ensuring that `<name>` isn't itself subject to alias expansion *before* the function is defined.
    - being able to pick a `<name>` that is also a shell *keyword*;
      note that such a function can *only* be invoked in *quoted* form; e.g., `\while`.
    - (In the case of `ksh`, using `function` syntax additionally implies that `typeset` statements create *local* variables.)
  - `dash`, `ksh`, and `bash` *when in POSIX mode* additionally prevent naming functions for *special* builtins (e.g., `unset`, `break`, `set`, `shift`); the list of POSIX-defined special builtins can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html); both `dash` and `ksh` add a few more that cannot be redefined (e.g., `local` in `dash`; `typeset` and `unalias` in `ksh`), but both shells have additional, *non-special* builtins that *can* be redefined (e.g., `type`).
    Note that in the case of `ksh` the above rules apply irrespective of whether `function` syntax is used or not.
- Potential sources of *environment shell functions* in scope for your code:

  - Note: The simplest way to guard against these is to use the (unmodified) `command` builtin (in `zsh` with `options[POSIX_BUILTINS]=on`, to prevent bypassing of builtins as well) whenever you want to call a builtin or external utility.
  - POSIX mandates that a script specified by its absolute path in environment variable `ENV` be *sourced* for *interactive* shells (with some restrictions - see [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03)); `ksh` and `dash` always honor that, whereas `bash` only does so when invoked as `sh` or, in v4.2+, with `--posix`; by contrast, `zsh` never honors this variable.

    - Note: Your code run as a *script* would normally run in a *non-interactive* shell, but that's not guaranteed; e.g., your code could be *sourced* from an interactive script, or someone could invoke your script with, e.g., `sh -i` to force an interactive instance.
  - `bash` has *2* mechanisms:

    - Exporting individual *functions* with `export -f` or `declare -fx` (the other shells only support exporting *variables*)
    - Specifying the full path of a script to source whenever a *non-interactive* shell is started in optional environment variable `BASH_ENV`.
  - `ksh` supports *auto-loading* of functions via the optional `FPATH` environment variable: files containing function definitions located in any directory specified in `FPATH` are *implicitly and automatically* loaded.

    - (`zsh` supports `FPATH` too, but auto-loading functions requires an *explicit* `autoload <name>` statement, so unless you specifically ask for a function by a given name to auto-load, no functions will be added to your shell.)
  - `zsh` supports sourcing scripts for *any* `zsh` instance (whether interactive or not) via its `/etc/zshenv` and `~/.zhsenv` initialization files.
  - (`dash` appears not to support *any* mechanism for defining functions via the environment.)

---

#### Workaround for `bash`: Ensure that `unset` has its original meaning:

*This workaround is only safe if you know that `bash` will be executing your script, which, unfortunately, cannot itself be guaranteed.*

Also, because it modifies the shell environment (removal of aliases and functions), it is not suitable for scripts that are *designed to be sourced*.

As stated, it's usually not desirable to run your code in Bash's POSIX compatibility mode, but you can *temporarily* activate it in order to ensure that `unset` is not shadowed by a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

# *Temporarily* force Bash into POSIX compatibility mode, where `unset` cannot 
# be shadowed, which allows us to undefine any `unset` *function* as well
# as other functions that may shadow crucial commands.
# Note: Fortunately, POSIXLY_CORRECT= works even without `export`, because
#       use of `export` is not safe at this point.
#       By contrast, a simple assignment cannot be tampered with.
POSIXLY_CORRECT=

# If defined, unset unset() and other functions that may shadow crucial commands.
# Note the \ prefix to ensure that aliases are bypassed.
\unset -f unset unalias read declare

# Remove all aliases.
# (Note that while alias expansion is off by default in scripts, it may
#  have been turned on explicitly in a tampered-with environment.)
\unalias -a  # Note: After this, \ to bypass aliases is no longer needed.

# Now it is safe to turn POSIX mode back off, so as to reenable all Bash
# features.
unset POSIXLY_CORRECT

# Now UNDEFINE ALL REMAINING FUNCTIONS:
# Note that we do this AFTER switching back from POSIX mode, because
# Bash in its default mode allows defining functions with nonstandard names
# such as `[` or `z?`, and such functions can also only be *unset* while
# in default mode.
# Also note that we needn't worry about keywords `while`, `do` and `done`
# being shadowed by functions, because the only way to invoke such functions
# (which you can only define with the nonstandard `function` keyword) would
# be with `\` (e.g., `\while`).
while read _ _ n; do unset -f "$n"; done < <(declare -F)

# IN THE REST OF THE SCRIPT:
#  - It is now safe to call *builtins* as-is.
#  - *External utilities* should be invoked:
#      - by full path, if feasible
#      - and/or, in the case of *standard utilities*, with
#        command -p, which uses a minimal $PATH definition that only
#        comprises the locations of standard utilities.
#      - alternatively, as @jarno suggests, you can redefine your $PATH
#        to contain standard locations only, after which you can invoke
#        standard utilities by name only, as usual:
#          PATH=$(command -p getconf PATH)

# Example command:
# Verify that `unset` now refers to the *builtin*:
type unset
```

**Test command:**

Assume that the above code was saved to file `script` in the current dir.

The following command simulates a tampered-with environment where `unset` is shadowed by both an alias and a function, and file `script` is *sourced*, causing it to see the function and, when sourced interactively, to expand the alias too:

```
$ (unset() { echo hi; }; alias unset='echo here'; . ./script)
unset is a shell builtin
```

`type unset` outputting `unset is a shell builtin` is proof that both the function and the alias shadowing the builtin `unset` were deactivated.

Comment: [Zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) states that `unalias` has option `-a`. That documentation is for Zsh version 5.2. In my experience in Zsh 5.0.2 (available in Ubuntu 14.04 repository) does not have the option for `unalias`, and Zsh 5.1.1 (available in Ubuntu 15.10 repository) has the option for `unalias`.

Comment: Thanks; I've updated the answer; `-a` works as of at least `v5.0.8` - if you know exactly in what version it was introduced, let me know.

Comment: I wonder if in other shells than Bash a script can inherit exported shell functions from parent environment?

Comment: That is the topic of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885871/exporting-a-function-in-shell).

Comment: @jarno: I've updated the answer substantially: While _exporting_ function is Bash-only, there are other mechanisms, both in Bash and in other shells that you have to worry about. However, the best approach is not to try to anticipate the various mechanisms, but to always control what you're invoking: remove all aliases, call only functions _you_ define, for everything else use `command`.

Comment: POSIX-compliant function definition involves `()` after the function name.  Blanks between and around the braces are allowed, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @jarno: Thanks for the correction re `()` - fixed. Blanks around `{` and `}` are definitely allowed, and even _necessary_ after `{` - for background info, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37802469/45375) of mine.

Comment: But ` (  ) ` did not work in Zsh. In contrary what you tell, it can be made sure that `unset` is pure in Bash. See my comments to this question.

Comment: `foo (  ) { echo bar; }` outputs "zsh: parse error near `}'" in zsh 5.1.1. I mean the comments on top of this page.

Comment: @jarno: Yes, placing a space _between_ the parentheses breaks in `zsh` (your lack of formatting in the original comment didn't make that obvious), which is good to know, but how does that relate to this answer? Incidentally, the term _braces_ is used for `{` and `}`, whereas `(` and `)` are _parentheses_ in American English (and _brackets_ in UK usage).

Comment: Sorry for wrong term and wrong formating. The space thing was just a note about POSIX compliant function definition that you present in your answer.

Comment: @jarno: Thanks for the edit and the suggestion - I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

funnily enough, you already said the builtin name -- `command`

```
$ var="FOO"
$ unset() { echo nope; }
$ echo "${var}"
FOO
$ unset var
nope
$ echo "${var}"
FOO
$ command unset var
$ echo "${var}"
<nothing!>
```

this doesn't help if you're in a hostile environment where someone has created a `command() { :; }` function.  but if you're in a hostile environment, you've already lost ;).

when it comes to exporting functions into the environment, that's a bash-specific extension and you should not really rely on that.  POSIX shells (like dash) do not support that by design.

Comment: I don't want to use `command` before I have made sure it is not redefined like I try to do in the question.

Comment: if you're worried that `command` is being overridden, then you've pretty much lost.  every shell builtin can be overridden.

Comment: Manual page of `command` advises a way to ensure `command` is not a shell function or an alias in an example concerning starting off a 'secure shell script' (in EXAMPLES section): http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/command/. But that may fail, if `unset` is a user function.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I know what can be done...

```
#!/bin/bash --posix

# if e.g. BASH_FUNC_unset() env variable is set, script execution cannot
# get this far (provided that it is run as is, not as `bash script ...`)

unset -f builtin command declare ...

saved_IFS=$IFS; readonly saved_IFS
# remove all functions (shell builtin declare executed in subshell)
IFS=$'\n'; for f in `declare -Fx`; do unset -f ${f##* }; done; IFS=$saved_IFS
```

Comment: I see. `unset` built-in is used in posix mode. Are you sure aliases do not have to be taken into account? One problem is that besides `unset` the environment may have exported `[` as function, but you can not unset it in posix mode. So you have to switch back to bash mode for unsetting it. You can force posix mode by `POSIXLY_CORRECT=` even if the script is called as `bash script ...`.

Comment: To add to @jarno's comment: if you don't control the invocation, aliases are a concern, but you can bypass them by invoking the commands prefixed with `\ `.
Similarly, when it comes to generically undefining functions, _all_ of them are a concern, not just _exported_ ones (`-x`).
As stated, you must exit POSIX mode in order to also be able to undefine functions with nonstandard names such as `[` and `a?` (sic).
The possibility of names such as `a?` means that `for f in \`declare -Fx\`` is not a robust way to enumerate function names, unless you also use (and restore) `set -f`.