# Why doesn't this bash function work?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to make a shortcut function for `ls -rt`, but the `-rt` is not accepted by Unix in my definition. Why didn't this work? What is the solution?

```
lsr () {ls -rt $1;}
```

Comment: Works fine here, once I fix the syntax issues.

Comment: I tried to follow the syntax of a previous shortcut function I made: `mkd () { mkdir $1; cd $1;}`

Comment: You're missing a space after the bracket.  You may want to consider an alias as well.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) would help you catch such syntax errors.

Comment: for alias solution. note that alias doesn't work for script. so if you want to provide global functionality that works for script, use functions.

Comment: `alias` works just fine for scripts, provided you understand environment inheritance, so I'm not sure where that contention is coming from.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's a reasonable, if oversimplified, recommendation: aliases are not inherited from the parent environment (unless a script is being _sourced_), and the ones you define in your (non-sourced) script itself won't work unless you run `shopt -s expand_aliases` beforehand.

Comment: Use `"$@"` in place of `$1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your particular problem is that you need white space after the opening brace, such as (quoting properly and using *all* arguments as well)

```
lsr() { ls -rt "$@"; }
```

But you may also want to consider an alias since this is substitution at the start of the command:

```
alias lsr='ls -rt'
```

This is, after all, how many systems give you the very handy "long ls", with something like:

```
alias ll='ls -al'
```

You'll just need to make sure this is present in something that's called for specific cases as needed, such as in `.bashrc` for interactive shells, or in a file sourced at the start of your script itself (and ensuring aliases are expanded with `shopt -s expand_aliases`). Those are two possibilities but there are no doubt others.

Comment: I was just thinking it and found you said exactly what I was thinking already :D Cheers

Comment: Correct diagnosis of the OP's problem, good tip re aliases, but the last paragraph is confusing: scripts run in _noninteractive_ shells that do _not_ read `.bashrc`; even if they did, aliases wouldn't get expanded inside the script unless you ran `shopt -s expand_aliases` beforehand. Scripts that aren't _sourced_ run in a _child process that happens to be a shell_, which is not the same as a _subshell_ (a clone of the current shell's environment).

Comment: @mklement0, have adjusted the final paragraph to make it more of a "something to look out for" rather than "this is exactly how to do it". Given the complexity of how `bash` uses its large swathe of profile-type files, any comprehensive information is likely to dectuple the size of the answer and, since it's tangential to the answer itself (and the question has been closed as simple-typo), probably not necessary :-)

Answer (score 2):

add whitespace after `{`

`lsr () { ls -rt $1;}`

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the missing space after the first "{" ?

```
# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
#
# touch a
# touch b
# touch c
# ls -rt
a  b  c
# ls -t
c  b  a
#
# lsr() {ls -rt;}
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{ls'
# lsr() { ls -rt;}
# lsr
a  b  c
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been noted, **the `{` *must* be followed by *whitespace*** for the function definition to work.

**[shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net)** is a great site for syntax-checking shell code, which **would have caught the problem**:

```
lsr () {ls -rt $1;}
        ^-- SC1054: You need a space after the '{'.
               ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

As you can see, it not only found the problem, but also provided a helpful suggestion to double-quote `$1`, so as to make the argument work with filenames with embedded spaces and glob characters too.

As for ***why* the whitespace after `{` is needed:**

**`{` is an instance of a so-called *shell keyword*, as opposed to the so-called *shell metacharacters* `|  & ; ( ) < > space tab`.**

**Metacharacters *separate words* during parsing, keywords do *not*.**

In the case at hand, the `{` in `{ls` is *not* recognized as a shell keyword, because it isn't recognized as a *separate word* due to immediately being followed by `ls`.

Bash therefore sees single word `{ls`, which is unexpected at this position, and fittingly reports `syntax error near unexpected token '{ls'`.

Note that the closing `}` does *not* need preceding whitespace (even though you may want to add it for *visual* symmetry), because it is *preceded by metacharacter `;`*, which is by definition recognized as its "own thing", and thus implicitly causes the `}` to be recognized as its own word.

On a related note: Since the closing `}` is on the *same line* as the `ls` command, the `ls` command *must* be terminated with control operator `;` - otherwise, the `}` would be interpreted as *another argument* to `ls`.